# MySQL 8: Truncate table stuck in `checking permissions` state for minutes

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Sometimes but not always `truncate table` statements get stuck in `checking permissions` state for several minutes (up to 7-8 minutes).

I'm running MySQL 8.0.12 (for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL))
My tables are partitioned with around 365 partitions in each.

There are only 5 users (excluding root and mysql.). The 5 users are not tied to a specific host. Sometimes the same users is used from multiple hosts at same time.

Is this a known problem? What are the possible causes or solutions?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In common the *checking permissions* is a result of too many user accounts. Remove unnesessary (outdated, unused, etc.) MySQL logins.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the suggestions. We only have 5 users. I've added more detail in the question.

Comment: possibly related, but no solution: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/218269/1396

Answer (score 1):

Hence my advice not to have more than about 50 partitions in a table.  Or to abandon partitioning altogether.

What *may* be happening:  `table_open_cache` (or one of the other caches) may be too small, and, hence, thrashing.

To verify that theory, I need to check several things.  Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`, `SHOW VARIABLES;` and how much RAM you have.  More [*details*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning).

To critique the partitioning, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for at least one of the tables with a lot of partitions.

And you are `TRUNCATEing` a table with a lot of partitions?

If possible, look in the filesystem and list some of the files for that table.